# Lumen GET request parameters always return empty array

Tags: php, parameters, request, lumen

I'm building RESTful server within Lumen, but $request->all() always return empty array, when I passing query parameters to it. But Input::all() - shows query parameters. So, the question is - what am I doing wrong, and how to get parameters via $request->input() or $request->all()?

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php   
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request;

$router->get('/login', function (Request $request) {
    var_dump($request->all());
    var_dump(Input::all());
});
```

**Request example:**

```
curl http://rest-server.loc/login?testparam=testvalue
```

**Response:**

```
array(0) {
}

array(1) {
  ["testparam"]=>
  string(9) "testvalue"
}
```

**System:** Ubuntu 18.04, Apache 2.4.29, PHP 7.2.10, Lumen 5.7.7

Comment: Can't format nice output, so here is link  - https://pastebin.com/jMWYVkF2

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution. Should use **Illuminate\Http\Request** instead of **Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request** for Request type.